# Parsing field name with a colon in JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json

How can we parse if json fields contains a colon(:)? Like this:

```
{
  "dc:creator":"Jordan, Micheal",
  "element:publicationName":"Applied Ergonomics",
  "element:issn":"2839749823"
}
```

In fact I wonder how to do this with a library like restsharp, for mapping?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string json = @"{
            ""dc:creator"":""Jordan, Micheal"",
            ""element:publicationName"":""Applied Ergonomics"",
            ""element:issn"":""2839749823""
        }";

var pub = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Publication>(json);
```

---

```
public class Publication
{
    [JsonProperty("dc:creator")]
    public string creator { set; get; }
    [JsonProperty("element:publicationName")]
    public string publicationName { set; get; }
    [JsonProperty("element:issn")]
    public string issn { set; get; }
}
```

**OR**

```
Console.WriteLine(JObject.Parse(json)["dc:creator"]);
```

Comment: +1 Really good answer, just one note: you violate naming conventions of .NET (i.e. properties should be PascalCased)

Comment: is there any annotation for mapping the class name? like we do for fields.

Comment: there's a field name with dash (-) how can I deserialize, not possible in csharp.

Comment: @SerhatKoroglu Do what you do for `:`

Comment: @L.B your solution is working great ..but when i fetching integer number from json string it returns ZERO please help

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has property [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which can be used to override default name. This means that when you deserialize json value of property `dc:creator` is assigned to `Publication::Creator` property and on the contrary when you serialize C# object.

For example:

```
public class Publication
{
    [DataMember(Name="dc:creator")]
    public string Creator { set; get; }
    [DataMember(Name="element:publicationName")]
    public string PublicationName { set; get; }
    [DataMember(Name="element:issn")]
    public string Issn { set; get; }
}
```

If you choose to use `Json.Net`, @L.B's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since Newtonsoft is deprecated it is preferred to use `JsonPropertyName` attribute (especially in .Net Core wher it is native attribute) instead of `JsonProperty`. So it could look like:

```
public class Publication
{
    [JsonPropertyName("dc:creator")]
    public string Creator { set; get; }
    [JsonPropertyName("element:publicationName")]
    public string PublicationName { set; get; }
    [JsonPropertyName("element:issn")]
    public string Issn { set; get; }
}
```

Also please note that in contrary to `[DataMember]` it also work for collection properties (JSON arrays) if it goes about `Restsharp` deserialization.