# JSON: Colon in root objects name and collection of objects in it

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got an colon in root object, for some reason I'm not able to deserialize it.
I'll just want to get every entry in ngcp:customer, and us it for datagrid, list etc.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Structure:
http://www.felferhuette.at/box/public.php?service=files&t=e6c43f5e2f341f1bc91d2fb3d956a771

regards
Martin
956a771

Comment: Okay. Can you post a simple snippet of your JSON, rather than your link, 'cos I can't decipher your JSON to spot the problematic bit? Secondly, if you're not able to deserialize it, then you must have some code that has failed. Please post the code and the error message. Thanks.

Comment: Also, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089319/parsing-field-name-with-a-colon-in-json

Comment: Hi! I'll try, not able ro post code :-)

Comment: http://www.felferhuette.at/box/public.php?service=files&t=5b1816ae1db36ce362abcbad45fec1fd