# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize multiple object data

Tags: c#, json.net

My json data is as follows

```
{
   "channelData":{
      "pva:gpt-feedback":{
         "summarizationOpenAIResponse":{
            "result":{
               "textCitations":[
                  {
                     "id":"https://www.farmersdirect.com/",
                     "text":"some text",
                     "title":"Farmers Insurance",
                     "type":"unknown",
                     "entityType":"Claim",
                     "entityContext":"https://schema.org",
                     "url":"https://www.farmersdirect.com/"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }   }
```

I am trying to fetcg values from textCitations:[] e.g. "id":"https://www.yahoo.com/"
I am new to C# and Json Objects.
This json involves json nodes like "pva:gpt-feedback":{} which has : and -
Looks like I need to create multiple Objects to de-serialize this json.
Could anyone of you please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22089386/940834 There is useful answers here about deserialising when there are colons etc in the name. I.e. use `JsonProperty` attributes

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://json2csharp.com this web site for json to .net model.

[json to model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZSLx.png)

and after that just like this code..
 `IEnumerable<yourModel> list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<yourModel>>(result);`

Comment: or visual studios paste "json as classes" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

i created an object using this tool [this tool](https://json2csharp.com/)  (very usefull for C# dev if you use json often )
Your object should look like this :

```
 public class Result
{
    public List<TextCitation> textCitations { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public SummarizationOpenAIResponse summarizationOpenAIResponse { get; set; }
}

public class SummarizationOpenAIResponse
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class TextCitation
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string entityType { get; set; }
    public string entityContext { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can deserialize using :

```
var yourVariable= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(myJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dynamic` to avoid the creation of classes.

Here an example based on your json:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonText = $$"""
{
   "channelData":{
    "pva:gpt-feedback":{
        "summarizationOpenAIResponse":{
            "result":{
                "textCitations":[
                   {
                    "id":"https://www.farmersdirect.com/",
                     "text":"some text",
                     "title":"Farmers Insurance",
                     "type":"unknown",
                     "entityType":"Claim",
                     "entityContext":"https://schema.org",
                     "url":"https://www.farmersdirect.com/"
                   }
               ]
            }
        }
      }
   }   
}
""";

// deserialize jsonText with Newtonsoft.Json and list all the properties
// of textCitations using dynamic
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText);
foreach (var item in json.channelData["pva:gpt-feedback"]["summarizationOpenAIResponse"]["result"]["textCitations"]) {
    // list all properties of the single item
    foreach (var property in item) {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name + ": " + property.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YoungDev has definitely pointed you in the right direction. I use that tool myself and it can be very helpful. His answer misses a couple of lines that you'll need:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class ChannelData
{
    [JsonProperty("pva:gpt-feedback")]
    public PvaGptFeedback pvagptfeedback { get; set; }
}

public class PvaGptFeedback
{
    public SummarizationOpenAIResponse summarizationOpenAIResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Note the `JsonProperty` attribute. That says to the deserializer "this property has a different name in the JSON" and allows you to cope with JSON field names that are not legal in C#.

If you're not using the NewtonSoft JSON libs you'll likely be using System.Text.JSON so you'll need the `JsonPropertyName` attribute instead.

How will you know which libs are being used? If `JsonProperty` doesn't work try `JsonPropertyName`.